# How to get a lower bound on $|Mv|$ (matrix-vector product)?

Tags: matrices

Suppose $M$ is a square matrix (with elements that are continuous functions which are bounded above and below) and $v$ is a vector. I want a lower bound like $$|Mv| \geq C|v|$$ for constant $C$.

Do I have any luck here?

Comment: I'd call that a lower bound.  Do you mean $|Mv| \le C |v|$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Doh, I actually do mean a lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can't be a better lower bound than $0$, because it is possible to have $Mv = 0$ with $v \ne 0$.

Comment: Does it help in some way if we know that $v^TM^TMv > 0$ for non-zero vectors $v$?

Comment: Well, that says there is some positive lower bound, but doesn't tell you what it is.  In fact, the best lower bound is the square root of the lowest eigenvalue of $M^T M$ (the least singular value of $M$).

Comment: Thanks, do you know what I can search for to read more about your last sentence? "Least singular value" gives me just how to optimise the singular value.

Comment: You might look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Answer (score -1):

If $M$ is not zero, then there is a unique nonzero greatest lower bound.

If $M$ is nonsingular, then that best lower bound is $1 / | M^{-1}|$.

In general, see https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2010.02.014

Joseph Grcar, "A matrix lower bound", Linear Algebra and Its Applications, Volume 433, Issue 1, 15 July 2010, Pages 203-220